# Laravel 8.0, problems with @yield('content') make duplicity of the content section in other div

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a newly started project in Laravel 8.0, and I have a problem with views.

I have the following master.blade.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
           @yield('content')
        </div>
         <footer class="row">
        @include('layouts.footer')
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I then have a view that extends that master blade:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

HELLO

@stop
```

The problem is, when rendering the view, the information is duplicated. Appears once inside the container div so the @yield works, but is re-rendered in another div outside the container (main class="py-4").

Let's see if someone can help me with the problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Consider including your footer template, too. It's more than likely you have another yeild somewhere.

Comment: You are extending 2 layouts. I would also change `@stop` to `@endsection` since it is removed from the documentation in the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

HELLO

@endsection
```

### you extends two time

Answer (score 0):

You must add one extends, edit the code and do the code below

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content','your title')

HELLO

@endsection
```

that the right way to get the view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).